# Tikz node: color change when the mouse is hovering

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to get a change of Tikz node colors when the mouse is hovering on it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean in the final PDF? I don't think so. This would need some Javascript embedded in the PDF. In theory something could be done using the `animate` or `fancytooltips` or similar packages. But I'm unable to give a definitive answer on that.

Comment: My sentiments exactly.  "Ouf, this sounds hard."

Comment: Note that you don't have to (and in fact shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @Hendrick Thanks for the tip I'll bear it in mind in my next messages.

Comment: I think that it will be difficult to get this behavior for nodes which do not have shape of rectangles (circle, oval, ...)

Comment: Did you find out how to do this ? I did with `fancytooltips` but I have issues with the positionning.. so I would like to hear about your experience. Thank you !

Comment: @joseldsm No, I didn't. :-(

Comment: @AriannaAngeletti Ow too bad :/ thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3):

You might try something with the [`fancytooltips`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) package.  That's probably not what exactly what you want, but maybe if the tooltip was a copy of the image with the color changed it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be [ocgtools](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ocgtools/) which allow you to define some layers and active them by cliking somewhere. I think just moving the mouse is not enough.